# Full list of target_scopes to use in service account impersonation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

sample code that uses service account impersonation:

```py
# do first on terminal: gcloud auth application-default login
from google.cloud import storage
import google.auth
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials

target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only']
source_credentials, project = google.auth.default()

target_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
    source_credentials = source_credentials,
    target_principal='<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FULL_ID>',
    target_scopes = target_scopes,
    delegates=[],
    lifetime=500)

client = storage.Client(credentials=target_credentials)
buckets = client.list_buckets(project='<PROJECT_NAME>')
for bucket in buckets:
    print (bucket.name)
```

All the code examples I'm finding online only have this target_scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only` mentioned. I want my program to do more than just read_only. Where is the full listing of target_scopes that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Full list of scopes across several GCP services is published here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

I tried out a few and they worked. Can't say about all of them but if service account impersonation is also wrapping something like oauth2 then it would make sense that these would work.

Companions to `devstorage.read_only`:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`

Edit: Based on comment below by John Hanley, recommend to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` as a generic target_scope which should default to the same access that the service account has.

Comment: Scopes are a legacy authorization mechanism. In many cases, a scope has too many permissions for each resource type. I recommend assigning IAM roles to the service account and the scope **cloud-platform** when impersonating. This will help prevent **elevation of privilege**. This article has interesting information on impersonation: https://www.praetorian.com/blog/google-cloud-iam-designs-for-self-service-privilege-escalation/

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks, I checked the oauth2/scopes page again and it seems like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` is included in almost all services. Looks like a good generic value to put in and let the service account decide things.